# Синтаксическая ошибка в условном операторе

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, запутался в операторах...
Вот код:

```
<?php
echo "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1251'>";
$letters = "../letters.dat";
$data    = @file($letters);
$data    = @array_reverse($data);
$ncol    = count($data);
$ip      = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$file    = "ips.dat";
$ban     = file($file);
$count   = count($ban);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ($ip == $ban[$i]) {
        echo "Вы забанены";
    }} else {
        if (file_exists($letters)) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < $ncol; $j++) {
                list($login, $photo, $message, $time) = split(":::", "$data[$j]");
                echo "<table width='100%' class='message'>
    <tr><td><img src=$photo width='50' height='50'>&nbsp;$login</td><td width='50'>$time</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>$message</td></tr></table>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<center><font color='silver'><h1>Записей нет</h1></font></center>";
        }
}
?>
```

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы, при `$ip == $ban[$i]` выводилось "Вы забанены", а если это `false`, то выводятся такие операторы, которые идут, начиная с `if (file_exists($letters))`... Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А какую ошибку выводит?

Comment: Ошибка:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE on line 14.
14 строка - это else {
if (file_exists($letters))...
Тут можно вроде elseif... ну или какой-то оператор, где можно делать если так, то бан, если нет, то выводим следующие операторы, где если файл есть, то вывод данных, а если нет, то выводит "Записей нет".

Answer (score 1):

Разрешите вам сначала подсказать некоторые *важные*, на мой взгляд, пункты.
Вместо `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` попробуйте использовать `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`, иногда спасает в отображении реального `ip`, не прокси.

Также обратите внимание, что:

```
 for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){ if($ip ==
 $ban[$i]){ echo "Вы забанены";}} else
 {
```

Не сработает `else`, т.к. лишняя фигурная скобка.

Comment: Ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE...
Как раз из-за того, что лишняя фигурная скобка.

P.S. почему у меня код в комментариях на сайте не подсвечивает синтаксисом?

Comment: насчёт ip спасибо, насчёт скобки... я там запутался, но вроде вторая от for...

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста код, как вы видите его правильным, я просто немного не понял.

Comment: Так от чего должен else срабатывать, если вы if закрыли от него фигурной скобкой? Ваша ошибка как раз из-за лишней скобки :)

Comment: Вместое ... echo "Вы забанены";}} else { ... попробуйте  ... echo "Вы забанены";} else { ...

Comment: а как же for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)? это меня тоже напрягло и я запутался;)

Comment: так ведь цикл должен для всей части кодв срабатывать. В общем, попробуйте echo "Вы забанены";}} здесь убрать одну скобку, чтобы было так: echo "Вы забанены";} и скажите, что получилось. Потому что не все понимает ваш код.

Comment: если просто убрать ту лишнюю скобку, которая идёт от for, то всё так же остаётся, та же ошибка. Если же скобку приделать в конец самый самый ...</center>";}}} ?>, то он выводит Нет записей 3 раза, т.к. там три ip-адреса в файле(*.dat) и он их считает.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO имеет смысл данный блок

```
$count = count($ban);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
if($ip == $ban[$i]){
echo "Вы забанены";}}
```

заменить на более простую конструкцию

```
if (in_array($ip, $ban))
    echo "Вы забанены";
}...
```

по else идет далее по тексту

Comment: он выводит Нет записей...

Comment: в каком случае, когда пользователь забанен?
в вашем коде эта фраза выводится в случае, когда IP пользователя не содержится в списке забанненных IP и при этом не должно быть файла "../letters.dat", возможно файла таки и нет? Почему бы вам не указать путь к нему относительно DOCUMENT ROOT, а не относительно текущего скрипта?

Comment: я решил задачу по-другому, решил не парить мозг другим и упростить скрипт. сам скрипт - только кусок, инклудящийся в главный скрипт, я просто выполнил данный скрипт бана в главном файле, а под else поставил инклуд.

Answer (score 0):

Скобка не лишняя, просто **else** стоит НЕ после **if**, а после **for**.